# Setting docker environment variable to existing environment variable with different name

Tags: database, docker, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

My docker container requires database parameters to be specified via environment variables. In my situation, the database parameters are being passed into the container (using Cloud Foundry) as an environment variable that is a json string.

I'm able to pull the needed db parameters with this command:

```
${echo $VCAP_SERVICES | jq -r '.dbaas[0].credentials.username'}
```

But how do I set them to the environment variables needed by the docker image? The environment variables passed in by Cloud Foundry aren't available until the container is started.

Comment: Did you look at the ARG dfirective, the doc is here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Yes, I did look into it. That seems to affect environment variables that are passed at build time, so I don't think it helps in this case.

Comment: Is this a docker container that you built yourself? Or that you're using from Docker Hub?

Comment: It is a 3rd party container from docker hub. It is metabase/metabase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own wrapper container around the metabase container, like so:

```
FROM metabase/metabase
ADD run.sh /usr/local/bin/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/run.sh
```

And have a run.sh script that looked like:

```
!#/bin/bash

export DB_USERNAME=$(echo $VCAP_SERVICES | jq -r '.dbaas[0].credentials.username')
# more vars here as needed... 

# Now call the original entrypoint
/app/run_metabase.sh $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott Rankin's answer is correct. I found another option before I saw Scott's answer.  Because I was using cloud foundry I was able to use a manifest.yml file, like this:

```
---
applications:
- name: metabase
  command: |
    apk update &&
    apk add ca-certificates &&
    update-ca-certificates &&
    apk add openssl &&
    wget -O /tmp/jq-linux64 https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64 &&
    chmod +x /tmp/jq-linux64 &&
    export MB_DB_HOST=$(echo $VCAP_SERVICES | /tmp/jq-linux64 -r '.dbaas[0].credentials.host') &&
    export MB_DB_PORT=$(echo $VCAP_SERVICES | /tmp/jq-linux64 -r '.dbaas[0].credentials.port') &&
    export MB_DB_DBNAME=$(echo $VCAP_SERVICES | /tmp/jq-linux64 -r '.dbaas[0].credentials.database') &&
    export MB_DB_USER=$(echo $VCAP_SERVICES | /tmp/jq-linux64 -r '.dbaas[0].credentials.username') &&
    export MB_DB_PASS=$(echo $VCAP_SERVICES | /tmp/jq-linux64 -r '.dbaas[0].credentials.password') &&
    exec /app/run_metabase.sh
  env:
    MB_DB_TYPE: mysql
  memory: 2GB
```